# How to replace an image with another using a script?

Tags: image, replace

Is there a script that allows me to replace an image on a webpage (not my site) but without editing the HTML itself. For example, the image orange.png appears twice on that page, but I need a script that looks for orange.png and automatically replaces it by the image I want. Another example would be replacing the Google logo to use your own, but it isn't really replaced, it just appears to be. The image is not defined by css, it's in a div, and does not have an ID. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Absolyn - Welcome to SO! You may want to consider adding a bit more detail to your question along with any code you've written, or maybe a more concrete example of what you'd like the code to do. Cheers!

Comment: Are you looking to change what is displayed just in your browser window? If so, what browser are you using?

Comment: Yes I'd like to change what it is to my browser only, and I use Firefox. And I haven't made any codes yet, I'm new to all this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any that exist...you could do PHP but that would change the HTML output.  The only other way would be to use Javascript and load the whole document and try and find it...I could do something similar in PHP but not in Javascript yet...I would assume a JQuery start-off approach could be something like:

```
var wholesite = $(document).html()//gets the html
///then code to find and replace orange.png....
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use User JS, I guess.

JS snippet that replaces image with "mine" ID to http://path.to/your/image.png:
`document.getElementById("mine").src = "http://path.to/your/image.png"`

Comment: Yeah like that! But without an ID, because the image doesn't have one.